# Pass value from JavaScript to Velocity

Tags: javascript, velocity, polarion

I am running a Velocity query (in our project management tool "polarion alm") to count the defects we have in our project. Secondly I am importing a CSV file with JavaScript and generate an array out of it.

I am able to store the number of defects in a workitem (that is some kind of an object with different fields) via Velocity to use it for later needs.

But I need to divide a value from a JavaScript variable with the value from my Velocity query and then to store it (via velocity). I am able to use a variable from Velocity in JavaScript (e.g.: `var foo= "$fieldValue";`) but not the other way around, which I would need urgently.

Any Ideas? (It could also help if there is an easy way to import and extract values from a CSV file (which is attached to the site) with Velocity.

Comment: Velocity is a templating language on the server, once JavaScript gets to run (on the client), velocity is long gone. You have to post to the server again, maybe using AJAX

Comment: You will need to pass the javascript variable value back to the server where your Velocity code runs... either through a form post, or an AJAX request back to the server.